# enforce normalsize normalfont throughout book

Tags: fonts, titles, fontsize

I would like to put all the text inside a book (headings, etc.) into normalsize, normalfont, with the exception of any words that I specify as textit.

In the MWE below, some of this is accomplished. But the following are still in the wrong font or font size:

Title: too big

Author: too big

Date: too big

"Contents" title of TOC: too big and boldface

Page numbers of chapters in TOC: boldface

Page header: italic

Is there an elegant way to control this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalsize}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\normalsize\normalfont}
\sectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont}
\paragraphfont{\normalsize\normalfont}
\subparagraphfont{\normalsize\normalfont}

\pagestyle{headings}
\title{Latex Example}
\author{M. Tullius Cicero}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Ipsum}
\textit{This sentence is emphasized.}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Vestibulum}
\lipsum[2-5]
\chapter{Lorem}
\lipsum[6-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither `tocloft` nor `sectsty` provide means for the `title` , `author` etc. font

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldselectfont\selectfont
\normalfont
\let\selectfont\relax
\let\oldtextit\textit
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textit}{\normalsize\normalfont\itshape\oldselectfont}
\pagestyle{headings}
\title{Latex Example}
\author{M. Tullius Cicero}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Ipsum}
\textit{This sentence is emphasized.}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Vestibulum}
\lipsum[2-5]
\chapter{Lorem}
\lipsum[6-9]
\end{document}
```